# read output from Linux shell and store it to a JSON object

Tags: java, json, linux, ssh, telnet

I would like to read json output from a command on a linux shell.

I used jcraft to establish a ssh connection and used channel to execute a telnet command.

```
 String host="<host>";
        String user="<user>";
        String password="<pass>";
        String command1="telnet <ip>";
        try{

            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
            session.setPassword(password);
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.connect();
            System.out.println("Connected");

            Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");
            ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command1);
            channel.setInputStream(null);
            ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);
            InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();
            channel.connect();
            DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(channel.getOutputStream());

            byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
            int count = 0;
            int count1 = 0;
            while(true){
              while(in.available()>0){
                int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                if(i<0)break;
                System.out.println(new String(tmp, 0, i));
                String asksForUsername = new String(tmp, 0, i);
                if(asksForUsername.contains("login") && count <= 0) {
                    dataOut.writeBytes("<username>");
                    dataOut.writeBytes("\n");
                    dataOut.flush();
                    count++;
                }
                if(asksForUsername.contains("Password") && count1 <= 0) {
                    dataOut.writeBytes("<password>");
                    dataOut.writeBytes("\n");
                    dataOut.flush();
                    count1++;
                }
                if(count == 1 && count1 == 1) {
                    count++;
                    count1++;

                        dataOut.writeBytes("<shell command to get the json response>");

                    dataOut.writeBytes("\n");
                    dataOut.flush();



                }


              }
              if(channel.isClosed()){
                System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
                break;
              }
              try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
            }
            channel.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();
            count = 0;
            count1 = 0;

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

After executing the command to get Json response using write bytes, I need to read the ouput and assign it to a json object? Is that possible.

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following lines of code to get and read  message

// Gets an InputStream for this channel. All data arriving in as messages from the remote side can be read from this stream.
         InputStream in = channelExec.getInputStream();

// Read the output from the input stream we set above
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

Comment: ~ I am already reading the output using an input stream, the problem is I need to give some console inputs and read their outputs too. The final output i would be getting is a JSON, which i need to read and assign is to a String or a JSON object for further use.